# Does SODA-RUBY just work with specific ruby version?

Tags: socrata, soda

i am trying to use soda-ruby with ruby 2.1.7. I am trying to pull data from https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Transportation/Street-Hail-Livery-Permits/ Here is my code

```
  require 'soda/client'

    client = SODA::Client.new({:domain => 'data.cityofnewyork.us', :app_token => 'REDACTED'})

    response = client.get("cqre-9u3k", {"$limit" => 1, :licence_number => "AE977"})

    puts response.inspect
```

what am i doing wrong here? I get following error on my console.

```
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/soda-ruby-0.2.16/lib/soda/client.rb:22:in `generate_user_agent': undefined method `sysname' for #<Struct::UnameStruct:0x0000000323fdb8> (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/soda-ruby-0.2.16/lib/soda/client.rb:49:in `initialize'
        from shl.rb:3:in `new'
        from shl.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

I would really appreciate if somebody helped me out in this. Thank you

Comment: It looks like it's actually because you're on Windows, and the uname struct is different on that OS. I'm on a plane and won't be able to get a Windows VM set up until tomorrow, but I'll get that fixed in the gem.

Comment: Thanks.  But everything else is like that rite? That's how I am supposed to do?

Comment: Yes, except for the fact you spelled `license_number` wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try version `0.2.17` of the gem. I think I've got it working on Windows now.

Comment: getting ssl error :(, also sorry i am kind of noob. I am building my first rails application using this api. `C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)`

Comment: 99.9% sure it's your root CA certificates being out of date, it's a common problem. I've never addressed the problem on Windows (I've never done Ruby dev on Windows for that matter) but I think this will probably help: https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

Comment: i did that and still ssl error, if there anyway to escape ssl validation?

Comment: i pulled some info but  why is the license type a date? [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhtecnra5a1mc10/Capture.PNG?dl=0)